# Get data from server before component render in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm trying to get data from server and pass it to another component to list it. But that another component is rendered before to get data from the server. So I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: datalist.maps is not a function`.

How to get data from server before component render? Thanks in advance.

My `Main` component:

```
class Main extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            datalist : []
        }
    };
    componentDidMount () {
        this.getDataList();
    }
     getDataList () {
        axios.get('/api/get').then(res => {
            this.setState({
                datalist:res
            })
        }).catch(e => { console.log(e)});
    }
    render () {
        let datalist = this.state.datalist;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Data List</h1>
                <DataList datalist={datalist}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Main;
```

My `DataList` component:

```
class DataList extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            datalist : props.datalist
        }
    }
    render () {
        let datalist = this.state.datalist;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Data List Page</h1>
                <ul>
                    {
                        datalist.length > 0 ? (
                            datalist.map(x => {
                                return (
                                    <li>{x.action}</li>
                                )
                            })
                        ) :(<li>No todo(s) left</li>)

                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DataList;
```

After changing `DataList` class as below it's working. Can you anyone explain me how?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
    const DataList = ({ datalist }) => {
        return (
          <ul>
            {
              datalist &&
              datalist.length > 0 ?
                  (
                    datalist.map(list => {
                      return (
                        <li key={list._id}>{list.action}</li>
                      )
                    })
                  )
                  :
                  (
                    <li>No todo(s) left</li>
                  )
            }
          </ul>
        )
    }
export default DataList;
```

Comment: Your error message is clearly saying `datalist.maps is not a function` . Yes it not `maps` it is `map`

Comment: Sorry that is my typo error, I edited my question, still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also noticed that you are assigning the `res` directly to the state object, it should have to be `res.data` instead:

```
this.setState({
   datalist:res.data
})
```

You can do this to hold it untill it gets the data:

```
return (datalist.length > 0 && 
        <div>
            <h1>Data List</h1>
            <DataList datalist={datalist}/>
        </div>
    );
```

It will render only when datalist gets the data.

---

> #### Note:
>
> As per your last comment, I can suggest you that this feature is not yet available or it is still in experimental stage with `suspense` api. That will let you wait untill the component loaded completely.
>
> [You can check official doc for suspense here.](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html)

Comment: Now also same problem, DataList component rendered before to get data from server.

Comment: It will because you are telling it to do so in `componentDidMount` instead call it in `constructor` which is the first in the cycle.

Comment: `datalist.length &&` is a bad practice because it might accidentally render length of datalist in the view. Should be `datalist.length > 0 &&`

Comment: Thank you @Jai accepted your answer, React `16.6` added suspense as an experimental which the components will wait for something before they can render.

Answer (score 3):

Add condition in render function that datalist is not empty then only call DataList component.

And also change maps to map it is a map function not maps

```
 render () {
        let datalist = this.state.datalist;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Data List</h1>
               {datalist.length > 0 ? <DataList datalist={datalist}/> : null
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: It is wrong!  if the dataList is empty `No todo(s) left` should be rendered.

Comment: It would be better return a kind message like "No data to show" instead of null

Comment: The DataList list componenet rendered before to get data from server.

Comment: @dhamodharan that is the reason I have added condition if data list has data then only render

Answer (score 3):

This is not related to empty data. The default value of datalist is set as an empty array in the constructor of `Main` component. Your approach is correct except there is a typo.

In your DataList component:

```
datalist.map(x => {
  return(
     <li>{x.action}</li>
  )
})
```

instead of `maps`. Your code is showing some problem so IMHO, it would be better this way:

**Main**

```
class Main extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            datalist : [],
            loading: false
        }
    };
    componentDidMount () {
        this.setState({loading:true})
        this.getDataList();
    }
     getDataList () {
        axios.get('/api/get').then(res => {
            this.setState({
                datalist:res
            })
        }).catch(e => { 
            console.log(e)
        }).finally(() => {
            this.setState({loading: false})
        });
    }
    render () {
        let datalist = this.state.datalist;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Data List</h1>
                <DataList datalist={datalist} loading={loading}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Main;
```

**DataList**

```
class DataList extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Data List Page</h1>
                { this.props.loading ? (
                   <p>Loading data from server...</p>
                ) : (
                   <ul>
                    {
                        this.props.datalist.length > 0 ? (
                            this.props.datalist.map(x => {
                                return (
                                    <li>{x.action}</li>
                                )
                            })
                        ) :(<li>No todo(s) left</li>)

                    }
                </ul>
                ) }

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DataList;
```

It's very much likely that datalist is `res.data`, i.e in `Main` component:

```
axios.get('/api/get').then(res => {
            this.setState({
                datalist:res.data
            })
        })
```

Comment: This is the answer, but I would like to add that the question's way of handling datalist's state in render should be: const { datalist } = this.props and removed from DataList component's constructor.